# MSSQL can't understand what's happening with the action "having count(*) lesser than <some field of other table>"

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count, having

I've tried to understand some part of an exercise i'm doing and just couldn't get it.

There's a part where 'T' is selected, grouped by 'a' and than it's redirected to "having count(*) < T3.a",
and I don't know how to approach it.

I've tried googling this sort of thing and see if there are similar examples but all other examples were using regular numbers for ex.: "having count(*) < 5" and not whole fields for comparison.

The exercise is this:

[MSSQL exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw7QY.png)

```
create table T(a int, b int);
insert into T values(1,2);
insert into T values(1,1);
insert into T values(2,3);
insert into T values(2,4);
insert into T values(3,4);
insert into T values(4,5);

select T3.b, (select count(T5.a) 
              from T T5 
              where T5.a = T3.b)
from (select T1.a as a, T2.b as b 
      from T T1, T T2 
      where T1.b < T2.a) as T3
where not exists (select T4.a 
                  from T T4
                  group by T4.a
                  having count(*) < T3.a);
```

I thought that the having count(*) was comparing each value that was grouped by to each value of T3.a in each row and if all rows have met the criteria than the value is getting selected but I somehow get different results.

Can someone please explain to me what is really going on behind this "having count(*) < T3.a" operation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `HAVING` is like a `WHERE` but for aggregate functions. You can't do `WHERE SUM(YourColumn) > 5` but you can have the `SUM` expression in a `HAVING`. Have you had a read of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: @Larnu Thank you first of all of the response, I have read the documentation, but i dont understand what is going on when comparing Whole columns of tables to single values in the having statement.

Comment: This is the part that I dont understand: "having count(*) < T3.a"

Comment: What about it don't you understand, with respect, it's not a difficult expression; where the count of the rows (in the group) is less than the value of `T3.a`. What part of that are you unclear on?

Comment: Lets say that T3 has 3 rows, so when I do "having count(*) < T3.a" will each of the values getting returned from the statement be lesser than all of the values of T3.a or they should just be lesser than 1 value of T3.a and it doesn't metter if the statemnt is not true for all the values of T3.a? @Larnu

Comment: A clause is applied to a row/group, @Zvika. If you had `WHERE ID = 1` it wouldn't return every row if there is at least one row where the value of `ID` is `1`, it would only return rows where the condition is true. A `HAVING` is no different. If `having count(*) < T3.a` is false the row is **not** returned. It's a boolean expression. Again, I don't understand what you don't understand here, as it's a very basic boolean expression. Is the value of `COUNT(*)` *less than* `T3.a`? If yes, return the row, if not then don't. Again, what confuses you here?

Comment: I uderstand the bollean expression, I dont understand if the boolean expression is repeated in some sort of a "for loop" for each value of T3.a in the T3 table... and if it is found to be true for all of them will the value that is grouped by 'a' will then get retuned @Larnu

Comment: Again, a boolean expression is only relevant for the row(s) it is applicable for. A Boolean expression being true won't cause rows to be returned where the boolean expression is false; only the rows where it is **TRUE**.

Comment: I understood it now, sorry for my bad explanations, thank you! @Larnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To repeat myself from the comments, a `HAVING` is like a `WHERE` for aggregate functions. You cannot use aggregate function in the `WHERE`, for example `WHERE SUM(SomeColumn) > 5`, so you need to do them in the `HAVING`: `HAVING SUM(SomeColumn) > 5`. This would returns any rows where the `SUM` of the column `SomeColumn` is greater than 5 in the group.

For your expression, `HAVING COUNT(*) < T3.a` it would only return rows where the value of `COUNT(*)` is less than the value of `T3.a`.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's break this down to it's separate parts.**

First the `FROM`

```sql
from (select T1.a as a, T2.b as b 
      from T T1, T T2 
      where T1.b < T2.a) as T3
```

This uses the old-style deprecated cross-join syntax. It can be rewritten as a normal join:

```sql
from (select T1.a as a, T2.b as b 
      from T T1
      join T T2 on T1.b < T2.a
) as T3
```

If we analyze what it does, we realize that it is actually what is known as a **triangular join**: every row is self-joined to every row lower than it. This was commonly done when window aggregates were not available.

---

**`WHERE`**

```sql
where not exists (select T4.a 
                  from T T4
                  group by T4.a
                  having count(*) < T3.a);
```

This is a correlated subquery: `T3.a` is a reference to the outer query.

What this predicate says is: for this particular row, there must be **no rows** in the subquery.

The subquery itself says: take all rows in `T`, group them by `a` and count, then only include rows for which the count is less than the outer reference `a`.

Note that because it is an `EXIST`, the actual selected value is not used. I suspect this may not have been the intention.

---

**`SELECT`**

```sql
select T3.b, (select count(T5.a) 
              from T T5 
              where T5.a = T3.b)
```

We then take `b` from the first join, and the count from a subquery of all matching `T` rows. Again, this was common when window aggregates were not available.

---

**So the whole thing can be rewritten as follows:**

```sql
select T2.b, (select count(T5.a) 
              from T T5 
              where T5.a = T3.b)
from (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by a) as cnt
    from T
) T1
join T T2 on T1.b < T2.a
where T1.cnt < T1.a;
```

There is something not quite right about the logic in your query, but without knowing what the original intention was, and without seeing the table and column names, I cannot say. The triangular join in particular looks very suspect.